# Query for count and distinct

Tags: sql, t-sql

I should make a report in T-SQL from several table.
I can join all the table needed but after I don't know excatly how to get my information.

Explanation :

I've got the following table :

```
Tbl_User (UserId, Username)
Tbl_Customer (CustomeriD, CustomerName)   
Tbl_DocA (DocId, CustomerID, DateCreate, DateAdd, UseriD)    
Tbl_DocB (DocId, CustomerID, DateCreate, DateAdd, UseriD)    
Tbl_DocC (DocId, CustomerID, DateCreate, DateAdd, UseriD)
```

I am trying to get a report like this :

[image]

After I can get this, the idea is to have a filter with the date in SQL reporting.

Comment: At first glance this looks like a bad data model. Is there a reason to have separate tables for the different docs?

Comment: I'm not the conceptor of this....i should bring a result with that kind of things :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can union all the document tables together and join users and customers on it.

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID 
      ,Customer.CustomerName 
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DocType = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS doc_a_total
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DocType = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS doc_b_total
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DocType = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS doc_c_total
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DocType = 'A' AND user.username ='azerty' THEN 1 END) AS doc_a_made_by_azerty
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DocType = 'B' AND user.username ='azerty' THEN 1 END) AS doc_b_made_by_azerty
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DocType = 'C' AND user.username ='azerty' THEN 1 END) AS doc_c_made_by_azerty

FROM (
(SELECT 'A' AS DocType, * FROM Tbl_DocA) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'B' AS DocType, * FROM Tbl_DocB)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'C' AS DocType, * FROM Tbl_DocC)
) AS docs 
JOIN Tbl_User AS user ON user.UserId = docs.UseriD
JOIN Tbl_Customer AS Customer ON Customer.CustomeriD = docs.CustomeriD
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID , Customer.CustomerName
```

Comment: I should have thought about this myself :-)

Comment: Yes, so simple. I've over-complicated things in my answer, too. (It should be `UNION ALL`instead of `UNION`, though, and single quotes for strings, i.e. `'A'` instead of `"A"`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use common table expressions to get the count for each report type per customer, with conditional aggregation for reports made by a specific user, and join them to the customers table.
Something like this should get you the desired results:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = 1; -- or whatever the id of the user you need
WITH CTEDocA AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID
         , COUNT(DocId) As NumberOfReports
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN UserId = @UserId THEN 1 END) As NumberOfReportsByUserAzerty
    FROM Tbl_DocA 
    GROUP BY CustomerID
), CTEDocB AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID
         , COUNT(DocId) As NumberOfReports
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN UserId = @UserId THEN 1 END) As NumberOfReportsByUserAzerty
    FROM Tbl_DocB
    GROUP BY CustomerID
), CTEDocC AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID
         , COUNT(DocId) As NumberOfReports
         , COUNT(CASE WHEN UserId = @UserId THEN 1 END) As NumberOfReportsByUserAzerty
    FROM Tbl_DocC
    GROUP BY CustomerID
)

SELECT cust.CustomeriD
      ,cust.CustomerName
      ,ISNULL(a.NumberOfReports, 0) As NumberOfDocA
      ,ISNULL(a.NumberOfReportsByUserAzerty, 0) As NumberOfDocAByAzerty
      ,ISNULL(b.NumberOfReports, 0) As NumberOfDocB
      ,ISNULL(b.NumberOfReportsByUserAzerty, 0) As NumberOfDocBByAzerty
      ,ISNULL(c.NumberOfReports, 0) As NumberOfDocC
      ,ISNULL(c.NumberOfReportsByUserAzerty, 0) As NumberOfDocCByAzerty
FROM Tbl_Customer cust
LEFT JOIN CTEDocA As a
    ON cust.CustomeriD = a.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN CTEDocA As b
    ON cust.CustomeriD = b.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN CTEDocA As c
    ON cust.CustomeriD = c.CustomerID
```

To filter by date you can add a where clause to each common table expresstion.

BTW, The fact that you have three identical tables for three document types suggest a bad database design.
If these tables are identical you should consider replacing them with a single table and add a column to that table describing the document type.

Comment: There is other columns for each table but i need the one mentionned ablove only. Thanks for you reply

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. One key feature needed is to count a particular user apart from the others. This is done with conditional aggregation. E.g.:

```
select
  customerid,
  count(*),
  count(case when userid = <particular user ID here> then 1 end)
from tbl_doca
group by customerid;
```

Here is one possible query using a `cross join` to get the user in question once and `cross apply` to get the numbers.

```
select
  c.customerid,
  c.customername,
  doca.total  as doc_a_total,
  doca.az     as doc_a_by_azerty,
  docb.total  as doc_b_total,
  docb.az     as doc_b_by_azerty,
  docc.total  as doc_c_total,
  docc.az     as doc_c_by_azerty
from tbl_customer c
cross join
(
  select userid from tbl_user where username = 'Azerty'
) azerty
cross apply
(
  select
    count(*) as total,
    count(case when da.userid = azerty.userid then 1 end)n as az
  from tbl_doca da
  where da.customerid = c.customerid
) doca
cross apply
(
  select
    count(*) as total,
    count(case when db.userid = azerty.userid then 1 end)n as az
  from tbl_docb db
  where db.customerid = c.customerid
) docb
cross apply
(
  select
    count(*) as total,
    count(case when dc.userid = azerty.userid then 1 end)n as az
  from tbl_docc dc
  where dc.customerid = c.customerid
) docc
order by c.customerid;
```

Other options would be to replace the `cross apply` with `left outer join` and non-correlated subqueries or to put subqueries into the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the totals for the documents is another method.

Then use conditional aggregation for the counts.

*untested notepad scribble:*

```
;WITH SPECIFICUSER AS
(
  SELECT UseriD
  FROM Tbl_User 
  WHERE UserName = 'azerty'
),
DOCTOTALS (  
   SELECT CustomeriD, UseriD, 'DocA' AS Src, COUNT(DocId) AS Total
   FROM Tbl_DocA 
   GROUP BY CustomeriD, UseriD

   UNION ALL

   SELECT CustomeriD, UseriD, 'DocB', COUNT(DocId)
   FROM Tbl_DocB
   GROUP BY CustomeriD, UseriD

   UNION ALL

   SELECT CustomeriD, UseriD, 'DocC', COUNT(DocId)
   FROM Tbl_DocC
   GROUP BY CustomeriD, UseriD
) 
SELECT 
 docs.CustomeriD, 
 cust.CustomerName,

 SUM(CASE WHEN usrX.UseriD is not null AND docs.Src = 'DocA' THEN docs.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_DocA_userX,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Src = 'DocA' THEN docs.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_DocA,

 SUM(CASE WHEN usrX.UseriD is not null AND docs.Src = 'DocB' THEN docs.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_DocB_userX,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Src = 'DocB' THEN docs.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_DocB,

 SUM(CASE WHEN usrX.UseriD is not null AND docs.Src = 'DocC' THEN docs.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_DocC_userX,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Src = 'DocC' THEN docs.Total ELSE 0 END) AS Total_DocC

FROM DOCTOTALS docs
LEFT JOIN Tbl_Customer cust ON cust.CustomeriD = docs.CustomeriD
LEFT JOIN Tbl_User usr ON usr.UseriD = docs.UseriD
LEFT JOIN SPECIFICUSER usrX ON usrX.UseriD = docs.UseriD
GROUP BY docs.CustomeriD, cust.CustomerName
ORDER BY docs.CustomeriD
```

Those long column names could be set on the report side